# Progress percentage of an downloading file not showing

Tags: android, async-onprogressupdate

I'm using an AsyncTask and onProgressUpdate for downloading and showing progress.
It is running fine.

But I'm facing problem in getting the percentage of file that is being downloading from my hosting Godaddy, my files are in web site created with Wordpress in folder path like `/wp-content/uploads/myFolder/`

I tried downloading files from another web site, percentage showing fine.

```
/**
* Background Async Task to download file
* */
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

/**
 * Before starting background thread
 * Show Progress Bar Dialog
 * */
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(progress_bar_type);
}

/**
 * Downloading file in background thread
 * */
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
    int count;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();
        // getting file length
        int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

        // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

        // Output stream to write file
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
            publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

            // writing data to file
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        // flushing output
        output.flush();

        // closing streams
        output.close();
        input.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Updating progress bar
 * */
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    // setting progress percentage
    pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
}

/**
 * After completing background task
 * Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
    dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

    // Displaying downloaded image into image view
    // Reading image path from sdcard
    //String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/downloadedfile.jpg";
    // setting downloaded into image view
    //my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));
}

}
```

Comment: Code? We really can't help without it

Comment: is `lenghtOfFile != 0` true?

Comment: lenghtOfFile return -1